# Nginx fastcgi split path info with mailman

Tags: nginx, mailman

i'm using mailman with nginx to get its web interface this my nginx config :

```
location /cgi-bin/mailman {
           root /usr/lib/;
           fastcgi_split_path_info (/cgi-bin/mailman[^/]*)/(.*)$;
           include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
           fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
           fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $fastcgi_path_info;
           fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    }
```

it's seems to work good when i call `mydomain.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo`, but when I request something like : `mydomain.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/mylist` i get `403` and in nginx error log :

`FastCGI sent in stderr: "Cannot chdir to script directory (/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo)" while reading response header from upstream`

I tried every regex available to get it work but it still give `403` any help or any clue to get it work .

Comment: Are the permissions all good? And hate to ask, but does the directory in fact exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I find a solution somewhere: just comment out the

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $request_filename;
```

line in `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params`. It works, but I think it is nicer not to comment out this line, just swap the order of including this file and defining your own SCRIPT_FILENAME:

```
location /cgi-bin/mailman {
           root /usr/lib/;
           fastcgi_split_path_info (/cgi-bin/mailman[^/]*)/(.*)$;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
           include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
           fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $fastcgi_path_info;
           fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket; }
```

Now it works for me.